# How does the Earth's inner core gets heated?

Tags: geomagnetism

According to some references, it is said that the Earth's inner most layer gets heated up and exists in a solid form due to Earth's pressure. But how does that inner-most core get heated?

Comment: Maybe you could cite the references you mention? Are you specifically interested in only heating in the inner (solid) core, and not in heating in the outer (liquid) core, the mantle or the crust?

Comment: why dont you read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_core#Discovery . How it is heated? ideal gas  PV=RT , volume small pressure high,-->temperature high, there is still a correlation for metals https://www.jstor.org/stable/37180?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 1):

The inner core is not getting heated up - it's cooling. Much of the heat was released during the formation of the Earth, and the Earth as a whole is slowly losing that heat from its surface. Although a lot of heat is generated from radioactive decay, this only slows down the cooling. The entire core was once liquid, but as it cooled the center started to solidify and the solid inner core has been growing ever since. See, for example, [Earth as an Evolving Planetary System](https://books.google.com/books?id=6-X3CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=earth%20inner%20core%20evolution&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS5YKh05DfAhUpHzQIHUgOAlMQ6AEIMDAB#v=snippet&q=inner%20core%20heat&f=false) by Kent Condie (pages 145-146) and [The Inner core of the Earth](https://www.pnas.org/content/99/22/13966) by Don Anderson.

Answer (score 0):

the heat coming out of the core of the earth is generated there by radioactive decay of uranium and its radioactive decay products.

Comment: It would be great if you could reference some sources, and also describe how much of the heat is due to radioactive decay.

Comment: sorry, I cannot- but this is a topic about which entire textbooks have been written.       -Niels